# Spark Scala: convert columns into List

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following data structure representing columns name (first column) and values for it - something like that:

```
|col1       |col2            |col3       |columnname   |
+-----------+----------------+-----------+-------------+
|Very High  |High            |Medium     |predchurnrisk|
|Active     |Lapsed          |Renew      |userstatus   |
|Very High  |High            |Medium     |predinmarket |
|High flyers|Watching Pennies|Big pockets|predsegmentid|
|Male       |Female          |Others     |usergender   |
+-----------+----------------+-----------+-------------+
```

I want the variable domainvalues of type Array[(String, List[String])]

```
[predchurnrisk,(Very High, High, Medium)]
[userstatus,(Active, Lapsed, Renew)]
.
```

How this can be done with map or foreach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.collection.Seq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58355139/java-lang-classcastexception-java-lang-string-cannot-be-cast-to-scala-collectio)

Answer (score 1):

As a start :

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("Very High","High","Medium","predchurnrisk"),("Active","Lapsed","Renew","userstatus"))).toDF("col1","col2","col3","columnname")
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._
df.withColumn("arr", array("col1", "col2", "col3")).drop("col1","col2","col3").show
```

This prints the attached
[image]

may be you can take it from here , cheers!