# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.collection.Seq

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am doing something like this

```
val domainList = data1.select("columnname","domainvalues").where(col("domainvalues").isNotNull).map(r =>  (r.getString(0), r.getList[String](1).asScala.toList)).collect()
```

domainList should be of Type Array[(String, List[String])]

For input DF:

```
+-------------+----------------------------------------+
|columnname   |domainvalues                            |
+-------------+----------------------------------------+
|predchurnrisk|Very High,High,Medium,Low               |
|userstatus   |Active,Lapsed,Renew                     |
|predinmarket |Very High,High,Medium,Low               |
|predsegmentid|High flyers,Watching Pennies,Big pockets|
|usergender   |Male,Female,Others                      |
+-------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Error I am getting is

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.collection.Seq
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getSeq(Row.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getSeq(rows.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getList(Row.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getList(rows.scala:166)
    at com.fis.sdi.ade.batch.SFTP.Test$$anonfun$6.apply(Test.scala:53)
    at com.fis.sdi.ade.batch.SFTP.Test$$anonfun$6.apply(Test.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.mapelements_doConsume_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.deserializetoobject_doConsume_0$(Unknown Source)
```

How should I resolve this?

Comment: That means that the `1` element of the **Row** is a **String** not a _collection_.

Comment: Please share some input data and expected output.

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you please check?

Answer (score 0):

looks like that your second column contains String values, you can check it by using `df.printSchema()`. In this case you can try getting this list using `.split(",")`

```
.map(r =>  (r.getString(0), r.getString(1).split(",")).collect()
```