# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.Column cannot be cast to scala.collection.Seq

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am performing something like this for using right join in the spark application in java.

```
Dataset<Row> dataset3 = dataset1.join(dataset2, 
       (Seq<String>) dataset1.col("target_guid"),RightOuter.sql());
```

But getting this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.Column cannot be 
cast to scala.collection.Seq
```

Other than this, I couldn't find the way to use joins in java for the datasets.
Could anyone help me finding a way to do this?

Comment: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58355139/12116796

Comment: Yes sir, but this was for scala. i needed it in java.

Comment: which columns you are planning to join ?

Comment: @MoulikaPolisetty, can you check my answer and upvote + accept if it helps you?

Comment: @SomeshwarKale yes sir, checked . Please check the comment below your answer. Couldn't tag u there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to use below dataset api in java-

```
 def join(right: Dataset[_], usingColumns: Seq[String], joinType: String): DataFrame
```

then convert the string list into seq. Please keep below method handy to convert `java list` to `scala seq` as most of the spark apis accept `scala seq`

```java
import scala.collection.JavaConversions;
<T> Buffer<T> toScalaSeq(List<T> list) {
        return JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(list);
    }
```

Also you can't use `joinType` as `RightOuter.sql()` which evaluates to `'RIGHT OUTER'`. The supported `join types` includes -

```
'inner', 'outer', 'full', 'fullouter', 'full_outer', 'leftouter', 'left', 'left_outer', 'rightouter', 'right', 'right_outer', 'leftsemi', 'left_semi', 'leftanti', 'left_anti', 'cross'
```

Now you can use-

```java
Dataset<Row> dataset3 = dataset1.join(dataset2,
                toScalaSeq(Arrays.asList("target_guid")), "rightouter");
```

Comment: This is joining the data but count of the resultant dataset is way more higher(10 times higher than the two input datasets), not the unique ones comings out.

Comment: if you want the common `target_guid` from `dataset1` and `dataset2` use, "inner" to represent inner join

Comment: dataset1 has multiple columns , one among them is target_guid(primary)
dataset2 has only one column target_guid

I want to compare the target_guid's in dataset1 with the target_guid's in the dataset2. and target_guid's in the dataset2 should come out joining with the other columns of the dataset1.

Comment: can you post that as saperate question with proper input dataset and expected output? I think we resolved `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.Column cannot be cast to scala.collection.Seq`, no?

Comment: Have you raised the query? Please accept and upvote this, if it helps

Comment: The above solution is giving timeout exception.

Comment: Can you post the exception? i'm sure this is not related to this solution

Answer (score 0):

Can change your code to something like this,

```
Dataset<Row> dataset3 = dataset1.as("dataset1").join(dataset2.as("dataset2"),
                dataset1.col("target_guid").equalTo(dataset2.col("target_guid")), RightOuter.sql());
```

Comment: This command is throwing the below error:  

```org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'target_guid' is ambiguous, could be: target_guid, target_guid.;```

Comment: updated the code to avoid ambiguity @MoulikaPolisetty